# Не срабатывает transition:translateX через setInterval

Tags: javascript, css3

Есть слайдер с плавным пролистыванием слайдов. По клику листается правильно.  Добавил `setInterval` - пропала платная прокрутка, слайды меняются моментально игнорируя `transition:translateX`.

Подскажите, что может быть? Вопрос касается только последней функции `chengerHandler()`.

```
function slider(ul, slidenavblock) {
  var widthLi = ul.firstElementChild.clientWidth;
  for (var i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i++) {
    ul.children[i].firstElementChild.style.cssText = "width:" + widthLi + "px;"
  }
  var widthUl = ul.children.length * widthLi
  ul.style.cssText = "width:" + widthUl + "px;"
  var newBlock = document.createElement("div")
  newBlock.className = "slider-controls"
  var str = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i++) {
    ul.children[i].setAttribute("data-slide", (i + 1))
    str = "<span data-controls=" + (i + 1) + "></span>"
    newBlock.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", str)
  }
  slidenavblock.appendChild(newBlock)
  newBlock.firstElementChild.classList.add("active-slide")

  // Событие для переключения слайдера
  newBlock.addEventListener('click', clickHandler)

  function clickHandler(e) {
    var target = e && e.target
    var attr = target.getAttribute("data-controls")
    if (!attr) {
      return
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i++) {
        if (ul.children[i].getAttribute('data-slide') == attr) {
          var actSlide = document.querySelector('.active-slide').getAttribute('data-controls')
          if (attr - actSlide == 1 || attr - actSlide == -1) {
            ul.style.cssText = "width:" + widthUl + "px; transform: translateX(-" + widthLi * (attr - 1) + "px); transition: all .8s ease-in-out;"
          } else {
            ul.style.cssText = "width:" + widthUl + "px; transform: translateX(-" + widthLi * (attr - 1) + "px);transition: all .8s ease;"
          }
          cleanClasses();
          target.classList.add("active-slide")
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function cleanClasses() {
    for (var i = 0; i < newBlock.children.length; i++) {
      newBlock.children[i].classList.remove("active-slide")
    }
  }

  function chengerHandler() {
    setInterval(chenger, 5000);

    function chenger() {
      var cloning = ul.firstElementChild
      var cloned = cloning.cloneNode(true)
      var act = cloning.getAttribute("data-slide")
      for (var i = 0; i < newBlock.children.length; i++) {
        if (newBlock.children[i].getAttribute("data-controls") == act) {
          newBlock.children[i].classList.remove("active-slide")
          newBlock.children[i + 1].classList.add("active-slide")
        }
      }
      ul.style.cssText = "width:" + widthUl + "px; transform: translateX(-" + widthLi + "px); transition: all .8s ease-in-out;"
      ul.removeChild(cloning)
      ul.appendChild(cloned)
      ul.style.cssText = "width:" + widthUl + "px; left: 0;"
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", chengerHandler)
}
```

Comment: А это не потому, что у вас все функции и код вложены в `function slider()` ?

Comment: С вложенностью все хорошо, эта функция вызывается отдельно, проблема решилась добавлением setTimeout на время выполнения transition:translateX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набросал небольшой пример:

```js
var selectors = ['div#northSlogan', 'div#eastSlogan', 'div#southSlogan', 'div#westSlogan'];
var words = ["list", "of", "random", "words"];

function printWords() {
  var nums = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    nums[i] = i;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $(selectors[i]).removeClass('opaque');
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * nums.length);
      document.querySelector(selectors[i]).innerHTML = words[nums[index]];
      nums.splice(index, 1);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      $(selectors[i]).addClass('opaque');
    }
  }, 600);


}

printWords();
setInterval(printWords, 5000);
```

```css
div#northSlogan,
div#eastSlogan,
div#southSlogan,
div#westSlogan {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.opaque {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="northSlogan" class="opaque">northslogan</div>
<div id="eastSlogan" class="opaque">northslogan</div>
<div id="southSlogan" class="opaque">northslogan</div>
<div id="westSlogan" class="opaque">northslogan</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все заработало )

Comment: @DmitriyMorgul только дизлайк зачем? =D

Comment: Это не от меня,  хотел поставить лайк мне выдало ошибку что у меня маленький рейтинг для того чтобы ставить лайки